# WCF proxy classes for java soap service

Tags: java, wcf, soap, svcutil.exe

I want to create .net WCF Proxy classes based on WSDL which is describing java soap service. when I try to generate classes I get following error

```
Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is depend
ent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='mywsdl.wsdl']/wsdl:binding[@name='SomethingSoap12
']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='mywsdl.wsdl']/wsdl:service[@name='test']/wsdl:port[@name='SomethingSoap12']
```

svcutil generates .CS file but when I call service and look at the SOAP message it is different from what service expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by running svcutil.exe using online version of WSDL instead of dumped version of WSDL and xsds